# Running Java Spark Application on yarn but stop at bulkput to hbase

Tags: java, apache-spark, hbase

I have tested my application on master local with ideaj and every thing works fine. However, when I use spark-submit and set master as yarn, my application stopped at the bulkput method of hbase. Here is my code and config file of hbase-site.xml and spark-env.sh

```
System.setProperty("HADOOP_USER_NAME", "user");
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("appname").setMaster("yarn");
        sparkConf.set("spark.yarn.dist.files", "/opt/hadoop-2.8.0/etc/hadoop/yarn-site.xml");
//        sparkConf.set("spark.yarn.jars","hdfs://localhost:9000/user/user/jars/*.jar");
        sparkConf.set("spark.yarn.archive","hdfs://localhost:9000/user/user/jars");
        sparkConf.setSparkHome("/opt/spark");
        sparkConf.set("spark.shuffle.blockTransferService", "nio");
        sparkConf.set("spark.executor.instances", "30");
        sparkConf.set("spark.executor.cores", "3");
        sparkConf.set("spark.executor.memory", "5G");
        sparkConf.set("spark.driver.memory", "3G");
        sparkConf.set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "10G");
        JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
        Properties connectionProperties = new Properties();
        connectionProperties.put("user","postgres");
        connectionProperties.put("password","password");
        connectionProperties.put("driver","org.postgresql.Driver");
```

Hbase Operation

```
rdd = jsc.parallelize(list);  
      //list is a List contains string in format rowkey,cf,column,value
System.out.println(rdd.toString());
hbaseContext.bulkPut(rdd,
                     TableName.valueOf(tableName),
                     new JavaHBaseBulkPutExample.PutFunction());
//here is where application stop
```

hbase-site.xml

```
<configuration>
        <property>
        <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
     <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
        <value>2181</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
        <value>127.0.0.1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.support.append</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

spark-env.sh

```
export SPARK_MASTER_IP=127.0.0.1 
export SPARK_MASTER_PORT=7077 
export SPARK_LOCAL_IP=127.0.0.1
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
export YARN_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
```

Comment: What do you mean with "stopped at the bulkput method of hbase"? Are there any exceptions in the logs?

Comment: well, I forgot to mention that there is no exception in log. I even cleaned the warning showed in WEBUI, but application still can't go through it.

Comment: Did the spark job terminate? Or is it hanging? Was it able to open the connection to hbase?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt the spark job didn't terminate, it was just hanging. As for open the connection to hbase I don't sure about it since I didn't find any Exception and this application works fine with master local. However, my latest test suggests that the basic put operation with hbase api also can't work. Is there a method intend to check the connection of hbase?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt You were right my application possibly didn't connect to hbase. Is there any reference for me to reconfig my application, hadoop or hbase?